# function of と particle in 日本人をよく理解しようと一生懸命な人もいます

Tags: particle-と

> 日本人をよく理解しよう**と**一生懸命な人もいます

I don't understand the function of this particle in this sentence.
this sentence could be translated as: "there are also dedicated people **that** want to understand better Japanese people"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that has the explanation of that usage of the particle with this usage: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47519/22133

Basically it is a quotation of someone's speech or thoughts without the words 言う or 思う. You could translate the sentence like this

> There are also (even) dedicated people who think "Let's understand Japanese people well".

This is pretty awkward in English, but it gets across the idea that the people are *thinking* what comes before the と. Your translation is probably better because it gives off the same meaning and is less strange.