# What is the meaning of function of the と (無駄と) in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 士道はもう何を言っても無駄**と**つっこみを諦め、はあと息を吐いて問い返した。

Hi. Dear teachers.

What is the meaning and function of the 「と」 (無駄と) in this sentence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse it this way...

> 士道は『もう何を言っても無駄』**と**つっこみを諦め、...

The と is a quotative particle. It marks the thought of the subject (= 士道 here).

> 士道 gave up つっこみ, thinking 「もう何を言っても無駄」, and...

These threads might help:

- [Use of quote marker と before unusual verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/9831)
- [Embedded question followed by と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25361/9831)
- [Questions about 僕の時計が「7時だよ。おはよう。おきろ」と、起こしてくれるのだが、無意識に止めて、また寝てしまう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47516/9831)