# why is there no いう after と

Tags: grammar, particles

I found this sentence while sentence mining oregairu I understand it, but I don't know why there is no いう after the と can someone please explain this

> なんちゃってドッキリでした ～ と出ていけば　それでＯＫだ

Comment: Although と and いう are often combined to form という, と can stand alone without いう. Indeed, in this particular sentence it is wrong to use という.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47516/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"いう" is abridged from The sentence.

With　"いう"、you can say either
"なんちゃってドッキリでした ～といいながら出ていけば　それでＯＫだ"
or
"なんちゃってドッキリでした ～といって出ていけば　それでＯＫだ".

殊勝な心がけだと褒める

is same as

殊勝な心がけだといって褒める
("admires his credible achievement")